# Removing right recursion in yacc

Tags: bison, yacc, bnf

I have to rewrite a parser for a small DSL.
And I'm having trouble parsing the `if` statement.

Consider the following grammar.

```
command
command, command, ...  // multiple commands can be written in a line using ','
if expr {
    command
    ...
}
if expr {
    command
    command, ...  // in the if statement as well
    ...
} command, ...  // ugh!, command(s) can be written directly after the if statement
if expr {
    command
    ...
} if ...    // and if statement as well
/* ill formed!
if expr
{
    ...
}
*/
if expr { command } ...
if expr { command, ... } ...
if expr {
    ...
    command } ...
command, ..., if expr { ... } ... // command(s) can be followed by ', if...'
command, ..., if expr {
    ...
} ...
```

I know this grammar lacks in consistency (probably because the original parser is written in pure C) and hard to handle, but can't be changed anymore.

And I tried writing the yacc rule, but ended up in right recursion.

```
statlist
    : stat
    | stat EOL block
    | stat ',' block
    | ifstat block
ifstat
    : 'if' expr '{' statlist '}'
stat
    :
    | command
```

How can I remove this right recursion?

Or is it even possible?
If not, does other parser generator (such as ANTLR) solve my problem?

**EDIT**

Sorry, my question has been unclear.
So, think of it as this.

```
> s, s, s
command, command, command
> s, f, s, s
command, if statement, statement
> s, f s, s
command, if statement, statement, statement
> s, f f f s, s
command, if statement, if statement, if statement, statement, statement
> s s
error!: commands needs to be separated by a comma
> s f
error!: command and a if statement needs to be separated by a comma
```

to make this work, I came up with the following grammar

```
start
    : line
    | start line

line
    : b EOL

b
    : s
    | s COMMA b
    | F b

s
    : /* empty */
    | S
```

And I thought that right recursion will fill up the stack and 
 [is wrong](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Lex-YACC-HOWTO-6.html#ss6.2).

Comment: Why are you concerned about right recursion? Unless your code looks like `if expression { if expression { if expression { if expression { if expression { ... } } } } }` it's a theoretical problem.

Comment: @Kelvin Sherlock Well I thought solving the problem would not be so difficult, only that I couldn't think of a good way of writing the grammar. Thus, it might happen since it doesn't have a `elif` statement, and therefore the else if needs to be nested.

Comment: The grammar excerpt you pasted is really not sufficient to understand your problem. And neither right- nor left-recursion are problems, anyway. So please provide a clearer problem statement.

Comment: @rici I tried to make it clear, please tell me if my explanation still isn't clear enough.

Comment: If you have the choice between left- and right-recursion, you should choose left-recursion. Right-recursion does use more stack but there's plenty of stack so if you need it (as with right associative operators, for example) go for it.

Comment: @rici I used `int yydebug = 1` and found the stack getting piled for each `statement`, not only nested if (and it makes sense because right recursion needs to be reduced from the right to the left). I am about to parse a whole script file. I can't be sure if it really is "safe".

Comment: @vbstb: the stack limit is 10000 slots, which should be enough for a largish script. If it gets exceeded, the parser will return an out of memory error code (2). So you'll know; it won't overrun the heap.

Comment: @rici thanks, I guess I can live with that for now.